# Receiving a JSON object on an asp-net MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

i am sending a json-object to my asp.net server via jquery post. 
I am recieving a string like that:

```
"'{\"refNr\":\"124460\",\"dokid\":1}'"
```

I have no idea for an method, which can give a 
Dicitonary like:

```
dictionary[0].key = refNr
dictionary[0].value = 124460
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try JavaScriptseriizer, it has method convert to which might be useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: Thank you, sorry i cant vote your answer, which was very usefull!